# Can you get widescreen resolution from VGA connected to HDTV?

Tags: display, resolution, hdmi, vga, hdtv

I have a 21 inch BRAVIA Smart TV and I am, more often than not, using it as a monitor for my desktop. I have used a VGA connector to connect the desktop and screen. But the problem is that I get a resolution that is 1024x768 (square screen resolution) which is stretched on the TV to fill screen.

Is there a way to connect via VGA and get a widescreen resolution like 1366x768 or larger (if supported by the display)?

I have heard about this problem's resolution by using an HDMI cable, but my desktop doesn't have that port. So, **if I use an HDMI converter on the VGA cable and connect it to my TV, will I get widescreen resolution?**

Comment: One of my computers is hooked up to an HDTV using a VGA interface and I have no issues with 1080p - widescreen 1920x1080.  I would check the manual that came with the HDTV.  Some TV's limit the VGA signal they will accept.  It may be hard-coded in the TV to only go up to a certain resolution with VGA while the HDMI ports will do full 1080p and such.

Answer (score 1):

> if I use a HDMI converter on the VGA cable and connect to my TV, will I get widescreen resolution?

No. Not automatically, and/or if the problem is the fact that you are using VGA in the first place.

This is simply because a converter cannot introduce more data than is already there; it can only convert the data that is already there to some other form. For example, a VGA input to a HDMI output. The adapter would have no way of knowing what to display on the additional 281,088 pixels.

However, **VGA is perfectly capable of supporting the resolution you want** at reasonable refresh rates. *Something else* is wrong with your setup.

I would recommend starting out with **installing the latest drivers** for your graphics card from the manufacturer.

Comment: My desktop is kind of old. I use  an MSI motherboard but could not find relevant drivers. Is there a general driver that I can use?

Comment: @AnujBatwe That is a completely separate question, which shouldn't be asked in a comment (it doesn't seek clarification or suggest improvement of this answer, in the context of this question) but rather separately. Unfortunately, it would likely be closed as a product or service recommendation question, which we consider to be off topic. If you are unable to locate drivers, your best bet might be to contact MSI and ask them.